# Convert Mdx Query to Sql Query in Java

Tags: sql, mdx

My current system supports Sql Query. We are integrating our application with another application which generates the Mdx query from UI based on user selection. During the integration, we need to process this Mdx query and convert into Sql query so that we can use existing api to execute and process the query results.

I am looking for an api which converts Mdx query to Sql query.

Appreciate your help on providing details on this.

Comment: You might be better off rewriting the UI to generate SQL. Or providing an SSAS cube for the MDX to run against. Performance will be better - but it may not be suitable for your architecture

Comment: This will be so so difficult - you need to find a workaround - maybe explore Mike's idea